# ClickOnce: getting MSVCRT C++ DLLs on user's machine

Tags: c++, dll, clickonce, msvcrt

I've been trying desperately to get my application (15 C# dlls and 1 C++/CLI dll with C++ Runtime DLL dependencies) to deploy with ClickOnce. I got it to work by [just copying the Release folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291(VS.80).aspx), but ClickOnce refuses to copy the files (msvcm80.dll, msvcp80.dll and msvcr80.dll) and deploy them in this folder.

I did this nutty workaround (supply msvcm80.dll, msvcp80.dll and msvcr80.dll as Content/Copy If Newer and then at startup, create the Microsoft.VC80.CRT folder, copy those DLLs, and create Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest) that seems to work, but this all just feels wrong to me.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm stupid: I just found this:

On Publish tab of Properties page of my startup project: click Prerequisites... button > check Visual C++ Runtime Libraries, radio button setting: Download prerequisites from the component vendor's web site.

It seems to work the way one might expect!

Answer (score 2):

There should be a msi from microsoft that deploys those for you.  I used....

[instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299(VS.80).aspx)

and download vcredist_x86.exe[download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=32BC1BEE-A3F9-4C13-9C99-220B62A191EE&displaylang=en)