# how to include vcredist_x86 installation in a clickonce deployment

Tags: c#

After looking and looking I finally found the solution to one of my questions here on stackoverflow. The external dll which wouldn't work requires the vcredist_x86 package to be installed on the client pc.

How do I include such an install in my visual studio clickonce deployment? It isn't in the preqrequisites list nor can I find the reference in the list.

Any suggestions?

It's specific to the MSVCR100.DLL which is included in the package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClickOnce: getting MSVCRT C++ DLLs on user's machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213957/clickonce-getting-msvcrt-c-dlls-on-users-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me again. Nice that you could finally solve the problem :) I once had a same problem when I wanted to define an own prequisite. There is a very nice article on codeproject, which worked for me when I did it.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Add_Custom_Prerequisite.aspx

Comment: Great to hear from you again ;)